# python beautifulsoup can't prettify

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I seem to be doing something wrong. I have an HTML source that I pull using urllib. Based on this HTML file I use beautifulsoup to findAll elements with an ID based on a specified array. This works for me, however the output is messy and includes linebreaks "\n".

- **Python:** 2.7.12
- **BeautifulSoup:** bs4

I have tried to use prettify() to correct the output but always get an error:

**AttributeError:** 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'prettify'

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cfile = open("test.txt")
clist = cfile.read()
clist = clist.split('\n')

i=0

while i<len (clist):
    url = "https://example.com/"+clist[i]
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen (url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup (htmltext, "html.parser")
    soup = soup.findAll (id=["id1", "id2", "id3"])

print soup.prettify()
i+=1
```

I'm sure there is something simple I am overlooking with this line:

```
soup = soup.findAll (id=["id1", "id2", "id3"])
```

I'm just not sure what. Sorry if this is a stupid question. I've only been using Python and Beautiful Soup for a few days.

Comment: What's the type of `soup` after you call `findAll()`? Run `type(soup)`.

Comment: "the output is messy and includes linebreaks "\n"" - which output? Where are you getting this output that you're not happy with? The only thing that could output anything in the code you've given is `print soup.prettify()` which can't be it since you say it throws an error. What are you ultimately trying to do? What if you use the `.text` property on each element?

Comment: @CivFan surely it's `ResultSet`?

Comment: @AlexHall just trying to lead Eric to his own answer. `alecxe` nailed it in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are reassigning the `soup` variable to the result of `.findAll()`, which is a `ResultSet` object (basically, a list of tags) which does not have the `prettify()` method.

The solution is to keep the `soup` variable pointing to the `BeautifulSoup` instance.

Answer (score 0):

[You can call prettify() on the top-level BeautifulSoup object, or on any of its Tag objects:](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output)

findAll return a list of match tags, so your code equal to `[tag1,tag2..].prettify()`
and it will not work.